# Need assistance in solving exponential equation: $\frac{27^x}{9^{2x-1}}=3^{x+4}$

Tags: exponentiation

Find value of x: $$\frac{27^x}{9^{2x-1}}=3^{x+4}$$

My steps: $$\frac{(3^3)^x}{(3^2)^{2x-1}}=3^{x+4}$$
          $$\frac{3x}{4x-2}=x+4$$

Please help me finish solving, and correct me if what I did so far has mistakes. 
Thanks very much.

Comment: $$\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n} \\ \neq \frac{m}{n}$$ your mistake is this $$\frac{3^{3x}}{3^4x-2}=3^{(3x)-(4x-2)}\\\neq \frac{3x}{4x-2} $$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash I think you meant $\ne a^{\frac mn}$.

Comment: no,exactly I try to show "Arthur Alex Karapetov" mistake

Comment: @daryakhosrotash I don't think OP claimed $$\dfrac {a^m}{a^n} = \dfrac mn$$ just as I suppose OP does not think that $3^{x+4} = x+4$. What happened from line 2 to 3 was a wrong simplification using $$\dfrac {a^m}{a^n} = a^\frac mn$$ and then take $\log_3$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac{(3^{3})^{x}}{(3^{2})^{2x-1}}=3^{2-x}=3^{x+4}$, then $2-x=x+4$

Answer (score 3):

Your last step doesn't work, instead do:
$$
3^{3x - (4x - 2)} = 3^{x+4}.
$$